# Ruby gem Roo Workbook Sheets Each Row

Tags: ruby, iteration, roo

As noted in other posts here, the `roo` `gem` has some convoluted documents, and I can't figure out how to iterate through a `xlsx` `workbook`'s `sheets`, then each `sheet`'s rows.

[Roo gem](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo)

Iterating through each `sheet` only comes up with the `sheet`'s name, not a reference to the `sheet` itself.  So I have to declare it.  Still has no way of iterating through all `rows`.

```
s = '/Users/user3/Desktop/departments.xlsx'
a = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(s)
sheets = a.sheets.reverse

sheets.each_with_index do |index, i|
  sheet = a.sheet(index)
  sheet.each_row do|row|
    puts row
  end
end
```

Other examples on the `roo` documentation assume there is a `default sheet`, and a single sheet in a `workbook` file.  Not my case, so it gets confusing quickly.

How can I iterate through every sheet, then ever row, for testing and inclusion into my analysis?  The spreadsheet I'm working with has a blank column and many rows, and some artwork...typical office stuff.  These people are not data people.  Getting around their 'creativity' in spreadsheets is done by iteration and testing of every row, then stripping blank cells.

Anybody with some insight truly appreciated.

Comment: I will suggest you to use Creek gem if you only have to read.

Comment: @Rajagopalan Much easier.  Thank you.

Comment: Welcome, Creek is the fastest reading gem as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a sheet name to `sheet` method, this method declear: [Roo::Base#sheet](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/roo/Roo%2FBase:sheet)

### example

```rb
file = 'xxx/xxx.xlsx' # your file path
wb = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file, extension: :xlsx)
sheet_names = wb.sheets # all sheet names in this workbook

sheet_names.each do |sheet_name|
  curr_sheet = wb.sheet(sheet_name) # change default sheet

  curr_sheet.each_row_streaming do |row|
     # do something 
  end
end
```

Although the above method can traverse all the tables, it also encounters the following problems when working with the sheet contents:

1. How to calculate the merged cells
2. How to get the cell style
3. If there are multiple tables in a sheet, how to determine the scope of each table
4. How to deal with the values of cells with formatting information

And so on a series of problems

I recommend using another ruby gem, or using another language for processing, such as java's poi or easyexcel

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

**Solved**: use the `Creek` `gem`.  Kudos to **@Rajagopalan** for this.